# Different kinds of object initialization

Tags: c#, constructor, initialization

Hi
I was wondering if there is any difference between initializing object like this

```
MyClass calass = new MyClass()
{
  firstProperty = "text",
  secondProperty = "text"
}
```

and initializaing object like this

```
MyClass calass = new MyClass   // no brackets
{
  firstProperty = "text",
  secondProperty = "text"
}
```

I was also wondering what is the name of this kind of initialization

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Nope, absolutely no difference. In both cases you're using an *object initializer expression*. Object initializers were introduced in C# 3.

In both cases, this is exactly equivalent to:

```
// tmp is a hidden variable, effectively. You don't get to see it.
MyClass tmp = new MyClass(); 
tmp.firstProperty = "text";
tmp.secondProperty = "text";

// This is your "real" variable
MyClass calass = tmp;
```

Note how the assignment to `calass` only happens *after* the properties have been assigned - just as you'd expect from the source code. (In some cases I believe the C# compiler can effectively remove the extra variable and rearrange the assignments, but it has to *observably* behave like this translation. It can certainly make a difference if you're reassigning an existing variable.)

EDIT: Slight subtle point about omitting constructor arguments. If you do so, it's always equivalent to including an empty argument list - but that's *not* the same as being equivalent to calling the parameterless constructor. For example, there can be optional parameters, or parameter arrays:

```
using System;
class Test
{
    int y;

    Test(int x = 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(x);
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        // This is still okay, even though there's no geniune parameterless
        // constructor
        Test t = new Test
        {
            y = 10
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Could You tell me if I use initializer expression the default constructor will be called ?

Comment: @Berial: Both of them are object initializer expressions - but yes, if you don't specify an argument list for the constructor, it will be as if you had specified an empty argument list.

Answer (score 3):

Nope. In fact, ReSharper would complain that the brackets of a parameterless constructor with initializer are redundant. You would (obviously) still need them if you were using a constructor with one or more parameters, but since this isn't the case just remove them.